# Was the Southern Hemisphere cooler during the Younger Dryas?

Tags: climate, younger-dryas

The Younger Dryas was associated with less heat transport from the Southern Hemisphere to the Northern Hemisphere (and a lower flux of the meridional overturning circulation).

So I'm wondering - what were the temperatures of the SH like during that period?

Answer (score 7):

According to the paper [The Younger Dryas Climate Event](http://people.oregonstate.edu/~carlsand/carlson_encyclopedia_Quat_2013_YD.pdf) (Carlson, 2013), the Younger Dryas was a period of *warming* in the extratropical Southern Hemisphere, and quite a significant one as well, as, from the article:

> SST records show a warming
>   of 0.3–1.9 C from the southeast Atlantic to New Zealand

This is supported by

> Speleothem and pollen records from New Zealand and
>   pollen records from South America confirm that the Younger
>   Dryas was generally a period of warming

Citing glacial retreat measured in places such as New Zealand, the article [Glacier retreat in New Zealand during the Younger Dryas stadial](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v467/n7312/full/nature09313.html) (Kaplan et al. 2010) hypothesised the mechanism to be due to

> extensive winter sea ice and curtailed meridional ocean overturning in the North Atlantic led to a strong interhemispheric thermal gradient8 during late-glacial times, in turn leading to increased upwelling and $\mathrm{CO}_2$ release from the Southern Ocean, thereby triggering Southern Hemisphere warming during the northern Younger Dryas.

Research on the deposits observed in the Australian tropics of the age in the article [Late Pleistocene record of cyclic eolian activity from tropical Australia suggesting the Younger Dryas is not an unusual climatic event](http://people.rses.anu.edu.au/dedeckker_p/pubs/20.pdf) (De Deckker et al. 1991) revealed that the southern tropics experienced a drying phase, that fits well with a cyclic climatic phase.

In terms of the southern tropics, the article [Tropical climates in the game of two hemispheres revealed by
abrupt climatic change](http://horizon.documentation.ird.fr/exl-doc/pleins_textes/pleins_textes_7/divers2/010028119.pdf) (Ledru et al. 2002) suggest that there were significant variations, as recorded in pollen samples from the South American tropics, leading the authors to suggest that

> One consequence of the Younger Dryas changes would be the location of the Intratropical Convergence Zone in a southern position, so that even tropical regions would have been under Arctic influence.